# Bifilar Pendulum Equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

This is my first post so I am not sure exactly how to do all the notation so this may be weird but please bear with.

I am trying to finish my physics internal which I did on the effect of differing distances between the suspension strings of a bifilar pendulum on the pendulum's period. I just have a slight issue as I cannot find the equation of a bifilar pendulum to use to determine a relationship and therefore conclude. This is the only one that I have found:

T=(2πr/D √(3g)) √L

Ok, so what is r and D? I am assuming L is the length of the strings? g is gravity?

So yep, I don't know that but I just assumed that r is the radius, and D is the diameter/distance. I tried both of the ruler and of the section between the strings.

One of my distances is 70cm, so this will be D. Gravity is obviously 9.81. The lengths of string that I used were 20cm. Radius is 35cm, because thats half of 70cm. So when I find the period for this example using this equation, I get

T=(2π x 35/70 √(3 x 9.81)) √20

which = 2.59s

The issue with this is that experimentally I got 7.7s (average) for 10 oscillations. So for only one oscillation I got 0.8s. Am I calculating this wrong or using the wrong equation?

So I tried again using r=50 (half of the length of the meter ruler I used in the pendulum) which gave me 3.7s:

T=(2π x 50/70 √(3 x 9.81)) √20 = 3.7

which is wrong. So I tried using D=100 and r=35 again.

T=(2π x 35/100 √(3 x 9.81)) √20 = 1.8s

which is closer but still not right.

Is this not the right equation? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Where did you find the equation?  The source should tell you what r, D and L represent.

Comment: Alternatively see http://voyager.egglescliffe.org.uk/physics/gravitation/bifilar/bif.html

Comment: It was used on an exemplar I used, and it was the only place I was able to find one :( I looked at this site but I am not trying to find the moment of inertia, and all the equations seem to have something to do with I which I do not use, but thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is the same as that in the source below, although the variables have different meanings.  In your formula r=100cm is the length of the rod, D=70cm is the separation of the two strings, and L=20cm is the length of each string.  These numbers give T=0.74s which is close to your measurement of 0.77s.

http://voyager.egglescliffe.org.uk/physics/gravitation/bifilar/bif.html

Comment: oh thank you so much! Sorry, I didn't understand the formula, but thank you so much!